# What is the name of the person that consults?

Tags: word-request

Working in agriculture, I deal a lot with consultants that advice me. So when I'm posing my doubts to those guys(a consult) what am I? What is the word meaning: "the person who consults?"

Comment: You deal with consultants who ***advise*** you. You are their client.

Comment: A person who consults *is* a consultant. So, your question is confusing. (But **you** are a client to a consultant.)

Answer (score 2):

**Consultants provide consulting services to clients.** You hire them or retain their services.

If you use someone's consulting services, you or your company are their client.